# providing workflow permissions to users

Tags: workflow

I've made an app and some users related to this app. Now i need to provide permissions to all the profiles. One of these needs to be given the ability to change a workflow. For this, I provided the profile with the 'Customise Application' permission. is there any other way to do it? Since this permission enables that user to customise everything then.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, the only way to allow a user to create and edit workflows is with the 'Customize Application' permission.  Why is it you need to provide all the profiles with this ability anyway?  Doesn't seem like all users would need this permission, perhaps just he sys admins, or a profile thats equivalent.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wfrules.htm&language=en

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtO0AAI

Comment: not all the profiles. Just one. I was just thinking if we could find a work around.

Comment: unfortunately there is no workaround.  As long as you are only providing a sys admin type profile with the permission, you risk is mitigated to some degree.

Comment: actually its not system admin that i'm providing the permission to. its marketing manager. :(